# In JXTable, root column is not taking other column color

Tags: java, swingx, jxtable

[image]

I used swingx for table.The first column is not taking color rendering of JxTable. Plz give your valuable suggestion. Thanx in advance.

Comment: hmm ... should work: what OS/LAF? Plus: any special renderer in the first column? And how do you achieve the row striping? Best to show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: OS:Ubuntu, LAF:None. no any special renderer in first column. I am achieving row striping by gradient rendering.